# Error compiling external C++ library in Android Studio Project

Tags: java, android, c++, cmake

I am trying to compile this [C++ GitHub repo](https://github.com/automatak/dnp3) into my android studio project. I added it as an external C++ library to my project and can compile and run the CMake build; however, if I try to add the Java bindings dependency `"-DDNP3_JAVA=ON"` as an argument to CMake I get a compiling error when trying to run `make project` and `build APK(s)`.

This is my build.gradle

```
android {
    defaultConfig {
        . . . 
        externalNativeBuild {
            cmake {
                arguments "-DDNP3_JAVA=ON" // This is the argument that casues the build to fail
            }
        }
    }
    . . . 
    externalNativeBuild {
        cmake {
            path '../../../../../dnp3/CMakeLists.txt'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    . . .
}
```

And this is the output I get when the build fails. I am not sure why it repeats twice in the console.

```
Build command failed.

Error while executing process E:\Android\SDK\cmake\3.6.4111459\bin\cmake.exe with arguments {-HE:\dnp3 -BE:\Users\xxxxx\AndroidStudioProjects\MyApplication\app\.externalNativeBuild\cmake\debug\armeabi-v7a -DANDROID_ABI=armeabi-v7a -DANDROID_PLATFORM=android-24 -DCMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY=E:\Users\xxxxx\AndroidStudioProjects\MyApplication\app\build\intermediates\cmake\debug\obj\armeabi-v7a -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug -DANDROID_NDK=E:\Android\SDK\ndk-bundle -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=E:\Android\SDK\ndk-bundle\build\cmake\android.toolchain.cmake -DCMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM=E:\Android\SDK\cmake\3.6.4111459\bin\ninja.exe -GAndroid Gradle - Ninja -DDNP3_JAVA=ON}

-- Check for working C compiler: E:/Android/SDK/ndk-bundle/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/bin/clang.exe

-- Check for working C compiler: E:/Android/SDK/ndk-bundle/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/bin/clang.exe -- works

-- Detecting C compiler ABI info

-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done

-- Detecting C compile features

-- Detecting C compile features - done

-- Check for working CXX compiler: E:/Android/SDK/ndk-bundle/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/bin/clang++.exe

-- Check for working CXX compiler: E:/Android/SDK/ndk-bundle/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/bin/clang++.exe -- works

-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info

-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done

-- Detecting CXX compile features

-- Detecting CXX compile features - done

CMake build is: Debug

-- Looking for pthread.h

-- Looking for pthread.h - found

-- Looking for pthread_create

-- Looking for pthread_create - found

-- Found Threads: TRUE  

-- Found Java: C:/Program Files/Java/jre-10.0.1/bin/java.exe (found version "10.0.1") found components:  Development 

 (find_package) 
Open File

-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!

See also "E:/Users/xxxxx/AndroidStudioProjects/MyApplication/app/.externalNativeBuild/cmake/debug/armeabi-v7a/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".

Build command failed.

Error while executing process E:\Android\SDK\cmake\3.6.4111459\bin\cmake.exe with arguments {-HE:\dnp3 -BE:\Users\xxxxx\AndroidStudioProjects\MyApplication\app\.externalNativeBuild\cmake\release\armeabi-v7a -DANDROID_ABI=armeabi-v7a -DANDROID_PLATFORM=android-24 -DCMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY=E:\Users\xxxxx\AndroidStudioProjects\MyApplication\app\build\intermediates\cmake\release\obj\armeabi-v7a -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -DANDROID_NDK=E:\Android\SDK\ndk-bundle -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=E:\Android\SDK\ndk-bundle\build\cmake\android.toolchain.cmake -DCMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM=E:\Android\SDK\cmake\3.6.4111459\bin\ninja.exe -GAndroid Gradle - Ninja -DDNP3_JAVA=ON}

-- Check for working C compiler: E:/Android/SDK/ndk-bundle/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/bin/clang.exe

-- Check for working C compiler: E:/Android/SDK/ndk-bundle/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/bin/clang.exe -- works

-- Detecting C compiler ABI info

-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done

-- Detecting C compile features

-- Detecting C compile features - done

-- Check for working CXX compiler: E:/Android/SDK/ndk-bundle/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/bin/clang++.exe

-- Check for working CXX compiler: E:/Android/SDK/ndk-bundle/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/bin/clang++.exe -- works

-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info

-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done

-- Detecting CXX compile features

-- Detecting CXX compile features - done

CMake build is: Release

-- Looking for pthread.h

-- Looking for pthread.h - found

-- Looking for pthread_create

-- Looking for pthread_create - found

-- Found Threads: TRUE  

-- Found Java: C:/Program Files/Java/jre-10.0.1/bin/java.exe (found version "10.0.1") found components:  Development 

 (find_package) 
Open File

-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!

See also "E:/Users/xxxxx/AndroidStudioProjects/MyApplication/app/.externalNativeBuild/cmake/release/armeabi-v7a/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
```

`Open File` links to line 147 in `FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake` in the SDK folder of Android.

```
macro(_FPHSA_FAILURE_MESSAGE _msg)
    if (${_NAME}_FIND_REQUIRED)    // Throws error to this line
        message(FATAL_ERROR "${_msg}")
    else ()
        if (NOT ${_NAME}_FIND_QUIETLY)
            message(STATUS "${_msg}")
        endif ()
     endif ()
endmacro()
```

Here is the [CMakeOutput.log](http://pastebin.com/Xuq9AYsa)

I have tried setting my JAVAHOME system variable to the following 4 folders but I get the same error for all of them.

- jdk1.8.0_121
- jdk-10.0.1
- jre1.8.0_121
- jre-10.0.1

I have also tried on run it on a virtual 64 bit Ubuntu system but get the same outcome